# How to read .epub file

Tags: c#, epub

As we all know `.epub` is a collection of files. Does anyone have an idea how can we read all that files embed in `.epub` runtime using `C#`?

Comment: I didn't knew that, ty anyways

Answer (score 8):

The ePub specification supports two formats, a collection of files or a package of files.  Most epub's use the packaging.  The package is simply a ZIP file with a renamed extension.

The specification [can be found here](http://www.idpf.org/specs.htm).  The OEBPS Container wraps around an ePub version of the Open Packaging Format.

The simplest way to read the content is to unzip the files and look at the xhtml files that were embedded within it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a zip file so how about using the Compression namespace to read the contents. Haven't use it but I'm sure this namespace exposes classes to read zip files as a stream.

Answer (score 0):

I found EPUB Sharp. Unfortunately, not released yet.
http://epubsharp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the gitden reader or you can use iBook if you are using iOS.

Free online ePub reader focusing on the social aspects of reading. Now closed, but the concept has moved to: http://www.readups.com/ per: http://www.bookglutton.com/

Source: **Wikipedia**

Supports EPUB 2 and EPUB 3. Books not readable directly on computers other than Macs.